# Why Microsoft word file is not opening?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-word

So i have a button that when you click it it will open a ms word file

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(@"D:\BatStateU-FO-OJT-02_Personal  History Statement.docx");
Process.Start(info);
```

This is my code it is giving me an error of win32Unhandled exception: cannot find the specified file.

Comment: Is the path `D:\BatStateU-FO-OJT-02_Personal  History Statement.docx` valid? Bearing in mind there are two space characters between `Personal` and `History`?

Comment: Just `Process.Start(@"D:\You file name with spaces or not.docx");`. The condition is that the file exists in the path specified and the name is correct (i.e., the file is *there*).

Answer (score 2):

A way you can do it, by start `MS Office` application via `Process`, and add your file's name that you would like to be opened as `commandline argument`, something like this:

```
    var myFileName = @"D:\BatStateU-FO-OJT-02_Personal  History Statement.docx";
    string PathToApp = @"C:\PathToYourMSOffice\Microsoft Office Word 2007.lnk";// or your version
    Process runProg = new Process();
    try
    {
        //With path to your MS Office application
        runProg.StartInfo.FileName = PathToApp;
        //Command line arguments to open file
        runProg.StartInfo.Arguments = "/t" +" "+ myFileName;
        //And start your application and also open file
        runProg.Start();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
       // do error handling
    }
```

Comment: I would not write anything as an answer if it doesn't work.

Comment: Do not recommend something like that. I only can repeate myself, I would not write anything as an answer if it doesn't work. Btw, I've used this code many times in my life.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to make it work without changing the codes. the reason why it is not working because the file has an older format while my unit has a 2013 version of a microsoft office i just simply save it as the newer versions of the word files.

Comment: There has never been a 2009 version of Word. 2000, 2003,2007 and 2010, yes. The file format (age)should not prevent Word being able to open a file. But if a doc format file has been given a docx extension *that* is a security barrier and will prevent a file being opened. You might want to investigate what the real reason was and edit your answer accordingly, to make it more useful for others encountering the same issue...